# jQuery Image Gallery with pop up

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have tried a lot to find a Image Gallery With Pop Up like this-:[Gallery](http://www.selfstorage.com/self-storage/california/san-diego/price-self-storage-murphy-canyon-65320/)
Can anyone give me some advice to develop that?

Comment: Please formulate a real question from the predicament you're in specifically.

Comment: Ankush creates a question and forgets to ask the question??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go http://www.justinbarkhuff.com/lab/lightbox_slideshow/ you can go to the examples section and find the exact thing.

Answer (score 1):

For popup use the following plugin
http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox

For Image Galley use the following plugin
http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/